# C# Windows Phone 8.1 create file container

Tags: c#, backup, windows-phone-8.1, containers, onedrive

I want to add multiple small `StorageFiles` (5-60 KB each) into one big container (ca. 1-3 MB with all files), that I can afterwards upload to `OneDrive` in Windows Phone 8.1.

What is a good and clean way to do that? Compression and/or Encryption is optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about LocalSettings? You may try to store your files there.

```
    public void Save(string key, string value)
    {
        ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[key] = value;
    }

    public string Load(string key)
    {
        return ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[key] as string;
    }
```

Comment: `LocalSettings` is for small files/settings only. It says in the Documentation, storing files there should be avoided. Also the files do not contain strings only, but DataBases

Comment: I ended up just creating joined `StorageFiles` in order to upload them to `OneDrive`